# How can I fix Ultima Online installed via Playonlinux failing to connect to automap server?

Tags: games

Recently, I have installed Ultima Online RPG game (UO) with PlayOnLinux
and also installed Ultima Online Steam (UOS, a subordinated program).
but failed to install UO automap (also sub-program)
Ultima Online automap (UOAM) indicated that it failed to connect automap server. especially use tcp port 2000~2005.
That is what I am troubled with.

Anyone to have installed UO on POL?
I want to share the experience to install UO with anyone who is interested in UO game.

Comment: read [ask] then [edit] accordingly to make your question clear.

Comment: I presume POL is Play On Linux. What is UOam? What all have you tried? Please edit the question to add these information.

Comment: Use https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=228 .